# Ruby code for Simple Tree Matching showing error

Tags: ruby

I wrote a code for Simple Tree Matching for matching two DOM nodes. It is showing some error. I am not able to figure it out.

I am posting the code and the error trace.

```
def tree_match(node1,node2)
    # ------- Implementation of Simple Tree matching algorithm. 

    if node1.name!=node2.name
        puts 'in base case'
        return 0    
    elsif node1.children.empty? or node2.children.empty?
        return 0
    else
        dp = Array.new(node1.children.size) {Array.new(node2.children.size,0)}
        i=1
        j=0
        j = j+1
        node1.children.each do |child1|
            node2.children.each do |child2|
```

## Line 180th. main error is in the code segment below.

```
                dp[i][j] = [dp[i-1][j],dp[i][j-1],(dp[i-1][j-1] + tree_match(child1,child2))].max
                j = j + 1
            end
            i = i+1
        end
        return 1+dp[dp[0].size-1][dp[1].size-1]
    end
end
```

ERROR:

in `block (2 levels) in tree_match': undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:187:in `block in each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in`upto'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `each'
    from /<>/DomTreeParser.rb:179:in`block in tree_match'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:187:in `block in each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in`upto'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `each'
    from /<path>/DomTreeParser.rb:178:in`tree_match'
    from /<>/DomTreeParser.rb:180:in `block (2 levels) in tree_match'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:187:in`block in each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `upto'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in`each'
    from /<>/DomTreeParser.rb:179:in `block in tree_match'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:187:in`block in each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `upto'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in`each'
    from /<>/DomTreeParser.rb:178:in `tree_match'
    from testDriver.rb:11:in`'

EDIT: nil class error is on line 180. I have marked it.

Comment: I guess you should initialize `j` before the inner loop (i.e. before line 179). You are incrementing it over the whole 2D array.

Comment: Besides, array indices start at 0, not at 1.

Comment: Yes.... but dp looks up i-1 and j-1 indices, so I have to start with indices 1

Comment: true. What about the initialization of `j`?

Comment: Yup .I fixed that. But still it's not working.

Comment: If you iterate over the whole arrays and start with index 1, you will access the array one beyond its end. Maybe increasing the size of `dp` by one helps. It would be helpful if you provide complete code and a test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You move past the boundaries of the array you created. Here

```
dp = Array.new(node1.children.size) {Array.new(node2.children.size,0)}
```

you initailize an array with `node1.children.size`, then iterate over **each** of them (`node1.children`) and try to assign
`dp[i][j] = ...` in each step.

Since you start with `i, j = 1, 1`, here's what happens on the last step of the loop:

`dp[i]` returns `nil` because `i == node1.children.size` and indexes are numerated starting from `0`. That's why you get

```
undefined method[] for nil:NilClass
```

when you call `dp[i][j]`

Can't really suggest a best course here since I don't see the entire code, but initializing a bigger `Array` should do the trick. Oh, and be sure to check out [each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)

Comment: Yes increasing the size of the array solved the problem. Thanks.